# Add file to subsite with C# knowing only URL?

Tags: 2010, development, sandbox-solution, object-model

I would like to use C# to add a file to a library in a subsite.

I believe `SPWeb`  will only reference the site I am on. In an ItemAdded eventreceiver, I want to use something like

`SPFolder myLibrary = web.Folders[myURL]; //this does not work. just an example
SPFile newfile = myLibrary.Files.Add(fileName, Stream, true);`

but on a subsite (Event Receiver is at the top level). I have a string with a destination URL such as "mysite.com/subsite/some%20library/file.docx." Within the ER, can I open the web and  and library to add the item there or do I need to split the string to get the subsite and library names each time?

Comment: Are you trying to route documents by any chance?

Comment: Yes I am. From the top of the sitecollection to any specified subsite based on the url that my users are entering.

Comment: Might be a good idea to take a look at the Content Organiser (2010 and 2013) functionality - http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/configure-the-content-organizer-to-route-documents-HA102772938.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OpenWeb` for defining the web. In case if I have understood your question correctly, something like the below code can be appropriate for you.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://site/subsite"))
{
// RootWeb returns the http://site and OpenWeb() returns subsite
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    { 
       // Operations to be performed can come in here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you get an SPWeb object you will be able to get reference to the library,  but for that you need to know the name of the library.

So a better to get the Site and LIbrary details from the url,  I dont think we have a way of getting library reference using the URL.

Comment: So the key is to trim the url to only the subsite level to use something like the following: `SPSite subSite = new SPSite(trimmedURL)`  and then try to get the library some other way?

Comment: yup.  SPList list = subsite.lists['library title / url']

Comment: Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist(v=office.15).aspx for a list of constructors on the SPList class

Comment: Great! Thanks.  Do have a follow up question if you don't mind:  the "by "url" in that last block, would I be able to enter the whole url as shown in the destination URL example above or would it need to be a shortened version?

Comment: It will be server relative URL.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlist.aspx

Comment: I know it is late but you could use SPWeb.Files.Add() method and add your file directly to the library using the full url without bothering retrieving the library object itself.